# Product Id vs License Number in WiX

Tags: wix

I would like to ask about the differences between product Id attribute and license number(user input on UI) in WiX. Are they same ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not the same. Product/@Id attribute is the Windows Installer [ProductCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The ProductCode property is a unique identifier for the particular product release, represented as a string GUID, for example "{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}". Letters used in this GUID must be uppercase. This ID must vary for different versions and languages.